# Is numerical stability preserved under basis transformation for pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm using a Backward Time Central Space method to solve the heat equation in polar coordinates. In Cartesian coordinates, it is easy to show this is unconditionally stable (by assuming solution of the form $e^{ikx})$. My question is, is showing numerical stability in Cartesian coordinates for a given method sufficient for showing numerical stability for a given method on the same pde but in a different coordinate system, namely polar coordinates?

If this is true, please provide some form of reference so I can convince myself.